# CakePHP, Helper class AjaxHelper could not be found

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-ajaxhelper

I am trying to do this cakePHP ajax tutorial found at this site: http://poli.bonzahost.net/2010/07/17/simple-ajax-call-in-cakephp/
But it doesn't work.  I made the database for it and made the table `brokers` with the needed fields, `id`, `name`, and `last_name` and added `created` and `modified` as 2 extra fields to the table.  I set the settings in the database.php file to point it to my host and user and database schema with the right password and all that.  I changed some things such as form->create, form->input, and ajax->submit to this->Form->create, this->form->Input and this->Ajax->submit, because I am working with CakePHP 2.1.2, not CakePHP 1.3.

But I get in my app: Helper class AjaxHelper could not be found.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.,

I think the AjaxHelper.php file is missing from my download of cakePHP.  I think it should be in: www\cakeAjax\app\View\Helper, but its missing from there.  Is that the cause of this problem?

If so where can I find a copy of the AjaxHelper.php file, and is www\cakeAjax\app\View\Helper where I would put it?  If not, how to I solve this problem?

Comment: ok - I found the Helper files, they're in: C:\wamp\www\cakeAjax\lib\Cake\View\Helper, but AjaxHelper.php is not there, the files that are there are:

CacheHelper.php
FormHelper.php
HtmlHelper.php
JqueryEngineHelper.php
JsBaseEngineHelper.php
JsHelper.php
MootoolsEngineHelper.php
NumberHelper.php
PaginatorHelper.php
PrototypeEngineHelper.php
RssHelper.php
SessionHelper.php
TextHelper.php
TimeHelper.php

Answer (score 2):

Ajax helper is deprecated since CakePHP 1.3.  You can now use the [CakePHP's JsHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html) for Ajax stuff.